# Typescript with Jest. Mock just one named export from module

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I'm having some trouble trying to mock just one named export from the module. Let's suppose we have the following named export getA, getB and getC. I just want to mock for one specific scenario the export named getA.

```
export const getA = () => "a"
export const getB = () => "b"
export const getC = () => "c"
```

Now on my test...

```
import {getA, getB, getC} from '../test.ts'

....
```

For one of my scenarios, I need to make `getA` returns something else but the rest of the named exports should not change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to mock `getA`, you can use jest mock factory to overwrite `getA` as mocked function, another named exports keep the original logic.

```
import { getA, getB, getC } from '../test';

jest.mock('../test', () => {
  const origin = jest.requireActual('../test');
  return {
    ...origin,
    getA: jest.fn(),
  }
})

describe("getA", () => {
  test('should return new value', () => {
    (getA as jest.Mock).mockReturnValue('AAA');
    expect(getA()).toEqual('AAA');
  });
});
```

Comment: what is './index' a reference to?

Comment: @mac it should be `../test`